# clearing the output stream c++

Tags: c++, linux, bash, terminal

Hello I'm trying to build a function grapher on the terminal in c++. I want that every time a new function is added the output will be cleared and the new frame will take its place.

I've tried to do system("clear") but I don't want all the terminal to be cleared and only the output stream. I've also thought about printing '\b' a lot of times but that seems inefficient.

I would also like to know how to delete 1 line.

Comment: Have a look at ncurses library if you want control over your terminal output.

Comment: I don't think there is any built-in facility(C++) for this.

Comment: Nothing in Standard C++ removes stuff from an output stream after it has been written to an output stream for the simple reason that with many streams after you write something to the stream it's gone.

Comment: Please remember that `std::cout` is connected to standard output which is data stream abstraction. It can be anything: printer, laser cuter, file, network connection ... . This abstraction brings many imitations what can be done. So you need something what is closer to console/terminal. I recommend ncurses library which is able to do it.

Comment: I recommend switching to a GUI framework or windowing style program.  Graphics are usually easier to use with these frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to work with console code.
[Console code about cursor](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html)
There are two solution.
Here is some C style code, just to demonstate the idea easier, you may convert it into C++ style.

1. Clear content

```
//Clear content after (x,y)
printf("\033[%d,%dH\033[J",y,x);
//x the column number,y the row number
```

2. Overwrite the content

```
//Goto (x,y) then print the next frame, it should overwrite the old content
printf("\033[%d,%dH",y,x);
...
//your code to output the next frame
```